# Wavelength-dependence of optical elements in integrated photonic circuits

Tags: optics, quantum-optics, quantum-computer, fiber-optics, photonics

I am interested in *integrated photonic circuits* or *silicon photonic circuits*. In the long run, I would like to analyze these circuits using a rigorous and analytical mathematical approach, taking the perspective of a photon that travels along the paths. However, essentially all of the literature that I found is very experimental or numerical. The latter ones usually go down to the level of Maxwell's equations and model specific geometries using electromagnetic fields. Does there exist a good reference (e.g. a book or review article) that treats integrated photonic circuits from a more formal high-level perspective? I imagine something that describes the basic photonic elements like beam splitters and phase shifters using equations that approximate well the actual experimental behavior.

A particular aspect that I am very interested in is the wavelength dependence of the basic elements. When I googled for literature, I observed that many papers only consider a fixed wavelength. All the papers that I found that do consider different wavelengths are experimental and consider experimental realizations of beam splitters and phase shifters that I could not find in any other literature. Also, they only show the wavelength dependence in the form of graphs like intensity plots, and do not even attempt to give an approximate equation reproducing these graphs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is exactly what you want, but here: https://opg.optica.org/oe/fulltext.cfm?uri=oe-19-11-10462&id=213860

Comment: Thanks for the article. But it's not really what I am looking for. It has three equations, none of which seem to talk about beam splitters or phase shifts. Instead, it seems to be about non-linear effects for second-harmonic generation.

Comment: Ok, I will look for another.